# Pass objects to another template without saving first (django)

Tags: django

Is there a way to pass a newly created object(not saved yet) to another page?

Currently, I have to save object A in page A before moving on to page B. After saving object A, I am able to get the id of object A and get all information about the new Object A from database, and this will aid in the creation of object B in template B.

The problem is because I was thinking what if the user decides to cancel operations on page B? By the time he decides not to create object B in page B, object A is already created according to above scenario, which I don't want this to happen. The whole process must create both objects and not just one model hanging. Even I do a delete of the previous object A, this will disrupt the increment of id of table A. Maybe doing an reset auto increment will do the trick, but i don't think its recommended.

I don't think i am able to pass Queryset objects(not saved) to template page B because it confuses me with the numerous `if request.method == POST` in one definition view and to counter this, to navigate to template page B , I used a different URL(diff def view) instead of giving a different template in the same definition.

Why I need to navigate to another page/view to create object B instead of displaying all fields in object A and object B in one page, because object B fields will vary and depends on what object A is. (Not planning to use dynamic pages)

I hope I'm not confusing anyone. I'll provide more details if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand completely but you could use django sessions to save the Object A (make sure its __dict__ method is pickable), then simply check in the session for existence of Object A to create Object B. You can set the expiration of the session to simply expire of Object B is not created (user cancels by closing the browser).

Comment: please remember to mark questions as solved if the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is using [sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions)

Lets say your model definition is as follows...

```
class MyClass(Model):
    ...
    ...
```

Probably you are using

```
rec = MyClass(params...)
```

instead of

```
rec = MyClass.objects.create(...)
```

so, after you create an instance (with or without saving to database) you can store that instance in **session**

```
request.session['somedata'] = rec
```

And when you wish to get it

```
request.session.get('somedata')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [django form wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) is what you are searching for.